# Purpose of high-performance compression algorithms besides storage efficiency

Tags: io, compression, gzip, zlib, lz4

While trying to learn from the source code of U++, a C++ based RAD framework, I noticed that it made heavy use of compression/ decompression to read and write data.
As far as I had understood, compression provided the advantage of storing data in a more compact manner while still maintaining integrity.

But as I looked more into LZ4 algorithm in general, some sources mentioned that it provides faster read/ write than direct read and write (Unfortunately I am unable to locate said sources any longer). I am wondering why this is that case if it is so, because no matter what, the main data still has to be processed - the compression/ decompression is just another extra step. Even if we consider a basic compression algorithm like Huffman coding, we are still having to examine the original data space either way, so a regular read, for example would do just that. But a compression algorithm would not only have to perform that step, but also then have to process that information further.

How could the presence of extra steps yield faster processing given that both a regular IO operation and compression/ decompression operation seem to be performing the initial data space read.

U++ mainly seems to use the zlib library heavily for writing/ retreiving app related resources. Is this done simply to use space efficiently, or for other reasons as well, like the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code written and running on a (c)pu operates* on original data space

(* exceptions apply, code can take compression method into account and work on it, eg. RLE data does not need to be decompressed for every aim to be achieved)

but from persistent data to processing circuit quite some many intermediate storages exist

and bandwidth jumps considerably, differently fixed and exponetially growing along the way depending on the "pipeline":

sd/hdd/ssd -> (_RAM ->) cache memory -> cpu/gpu register (latter having few bandwidth but extreme throughput)

and depending on whether the pu's are that of the PS5, a "generic" PC, from 2010 or from 2022.

I currently do not find any sources nor data giving rise to a generalisation of this but from what I remember having compressed data initially moved from a slow webserver(-connection) or hdd to ram or a client PC and then decompressed (entirely or range by range) by the cpu and put back in RAM or cache can be a significant shorter delay until processing the data than otherwise and this in most cases.

Ofc this depends on the compression ratio, the decompression effort and the pipeline pieces inbetween bandwidth and the overall data transported and the intended processing on it.

I didn't read anything about compression on the U++ website.

Decompression is an extra step taking time (think + *=1.01 time) but much more time is saved beforehand with transport (think - *=0.9 time) .

Comment: I've learned much from this answer. But in essence, compression is used because we also have to consider that data has to be transferred from host (local disk or server) to RAM. Is that the point? I accept that for online data, but for local disk, the general I/O would be faster, correct?

Comment: local system I/O can have the same issue depending on the type and model of persistent storage, transient memory and processing unit. A fast HDD today can deliver around 200 MB / s (https://hdd.userbenchmark.com/ add and sort by Read MB/s), the PS5 SSD can deliver 9 GB /s  compressed and cotains dedicated decompression hardware (https://www.tweaktown.com/image.php?image=https://static.tweaktown.com/news/7/1/71340_57_understanding-the-ps5s-ssd-deep-dive-into-next-gen-storage-tech_full.png).

Comment: Those comparable slow HDDs offer higher capacity in average though. For a 4K video, a single frame takes about 192 MB uncompressed. Using (lossy!) H.264 compression around 18 MBit/s can suffice to see a pleasant video @ 24 frames per second, this is around 0.09 MB per frame this is a compression ratio of around factor 2,000. The mentioned HDD would need around 1 s to send 1 frame uncompressed to the cpu this is a factor 24 too slow. The "compressed  frame" (compression is not per flat sliced frame of a video stream but in direction of per volume (frame * amount in time)) takes about 0,0005 s

Comment: to be sent but then incurs a decompression duration of about -- taking the PS5 gpu calculating at around 10 TFlops assuming those 0.09 MB frame are around 1,000 floating point values and require 5 operations each to achieve the uncompressed data this takes around 5,000 Flops @ 10 TFlops = 0, 000 000 000 5 s -- a total duration from sending to final image of about 0, 000 500 000 5 s which allows for a frame rate of about 1999 frames per second.

Comment: note 10 TFlops is 10TFlop / s and 5,000 Flops is 5,000 Flop.

Comment: inbetween these extremes compression can be sensible locally but rather requires some invesigation of the target markets hardware and calculating some durations regarding what one wants to achieve by ones data whether compression is benefitial. My hunch is compression is always benefitial but decompression performance must be appropriately fast.

Comment: for compressed data,
the 1st path is
storage -> memory - >processor. Duration = compressed size / the bandwidth of the bottleneck of these + compressed size * translation factor into number of floating point values * number of operations of algorithm to decompress / processor calculation speed.
the second path is
processor -> memory. Duration: decompressed size / memory bandwidth
the third path is 
memory -> processor. Duration: decompressed size / memory bandwidth + decompressed size * translation factor into num Flop * num operations for eg color corr. / proc calc speed

Comment: if this duration is less than when starting with uncompressed data, that particular compression is benfitial. When subtracting the "uncompressed duration" from the "compressed duration" replace compressed by "ratio * uncompressed". Then the "significant parameters" are the ratio of compression and the number of operations of algorithm to decompress besides the bandwidths and speed of the target hardware of which multiple likely exist.

Comment: looking at only 1* step, from transient memory (RAM) to processor (CPU), as a PC proc only has about 20 multi-purpose 64 bit registers (the cups which hold the data to be processed) only about 160 byte can be stored on it thus if the amount of uncompressed data which is to be processed for an intended aim is larger than this, having the source data compressed in mem is not sensible because the proc would store the part it can not directly start processing back uncompressed to mem just to fetch it later. But then the data can be uncompressed form the start, saves mem -> proc -> mem

Comment: assuming the compressed data has to be decompressed in a size which requires the "larger than 160 byte" (and not in chunks fitting into the regs) AND the intended aim can work with only those 160 byte at a time and does not need more data to achieve the aim.
* "1 step" because procs have cache: faster than mem storage, unfortunately this cannot be directed by a programmer, even multiple levels ranging from KB to MB in size, thus a progrmmaer can try to fetch larger than 160 bytes from mem and hope the  uncompressed data is returned from cache on next request, thus this is a 2 step scenario ag

Comment: ag = again. I leave details regarding number and size of registers outside because they vary across PC/mobile/more embedded and between generations and models therein, last time i looked i was surprised about the amount of intel x86 multi purpose registers in recent desktop cpus.

Comment: regarding working on compressed data RLE run length encoding can work directy on it for colors to eg replace one: 5*red -> 5*blue but can require decomporession to eg blur in y-axis of an image (RLE is across x-axis "usually").

Comment: I omited latency in the duration calculations above: duration between time of start of request and time of responder start sending first byte. They range from nanoseconds for ram responses and are in millseconds for persistent storage and even remote (internet) storage. @mindoverflow

Comment: thank you for sharing these. i do not completely understand some of these things because of my inexperience, but i'll will look up these matters in detail. i have one last thing to clarify, and i will post it here as a comment as soon as i phrase it properly. i would much appreciate your insight then as well.

Comment: i welcome you. in the meantime, "errata": 4K video: i made a 0-strain-effort of 4K = 4000 x 2000 pixel, I multiplied by 24 bits/pixel (SDR; HDR would be 30) but then wrote MB(yte) thus the ensuing calc is off by a factor of 8 (8 bit = 1 byte). 4K @ 18 MBit/s requires a very best match of content and compression settings, rather 80 MBit/s apply. I'm not sure whether data is put to RAM from persistent storage like by DMA or runs straight to the cpu along the bus. I gave integer register number as 20 but used floats otherwise (which (used to) have separate registers). FLOPS due to the "known" PS5